# Mostrar datos por ID en un modal

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Estoy trabajando en codeigniter 3 y tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al presionar el boton con el icono de ojo lo que quiero obtener que me muestre el proposito de un proyecto por el ID. Lo que he podido hacer es que traer todos los registros de la columna proposito de la tabla datos_grals de la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero lograr es que me muestre el proposito por ID del proyecto.
Este es mi codigo para traer todos los datos en la tabla

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">id</th>
      <th scope="col">Linea</th>
      <th scope="col">Proyecto</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre del proyecto</th>
      <th scope="col">Modulo</th>
      <th scope="col">Tipo de autorizacion</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre del solicitante</th>
      <th scope="col">Project Manager</th>
      <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
      <th scope="col">Proposito</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
if ($ver->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($ver->result() as $row) {
        ?>
                <tr>
                     <td><?php echo $row->id_datos_grals; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row->linea; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row->proyecto; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row->nombre_proyecto; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row->modulo; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row->pestania ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row->solicitante; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row->project_m; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row->fecha; ?></td>
                     <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></button></td>
                      <td></td>
                     <?php if ($_SESSION['rol_id'] == 3 || $_SESSION['rol_id'] == 1): ?>
        <td><a href="agregar-proyecto"><button class="btn btn-success">Ver/Editar</button></a></td>
        <?php endif;?>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#large">
    <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
  </button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-success" id="autorizar">Autorizar</button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-danger" id="regresar">Regresar</button></td>
                </tr>

                <?php

    }
}
?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

El codigo para traer los datos del proposito y mostrarlos en el modal es este:

```
 <div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Proposito del proyecto</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">

        <?php
        if ($ver->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($ver->result() as $row) {
      echo $row->proposito;

    }}
        ?>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
```

Tambien adjunto el codigo de mi controlador

```
    public function index()
    {
        //$data = array();
        $data["ver"] = $this->Administracion->mostrar();
        $data['view'] = 'listaProyectos';

        $this->load->view('layout', $data);

        //Mandar a traer el query del propositor
    }
```

tambien incluyo el codigo de mi modelo donde hago la consulta

```
public function mostrar()
    {
        return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM datos_grals");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por ahora, estás mostrando todos los propósitos en la ventana modal y deberías mostrar solo el que corresponde al botón donde se hizo clic.

Primero, agrega el propósito como [atributo de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) en el botón:

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#large" data-proposito="<?php echo $row->proposito; ?>">
    <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
  </button></td>
```

Luego, deja la ventana modal con el cuerpo vacío:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Proposito del proyecto</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">

        <?php
        // Cuerpo vacío, no agregues contenido aquí
        ?>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Finalmente, en Javascript, "escucha" clic en los botones para agregar el propósito en la ventana modal:

```
// Ejecutar cuando se hace clic en el botón con clase btn-primary
$('.table-striped tbody').on('click', 'button.btn-primary', function() {
    // Cambiar el HTML del cuerpo de la ventana modal
    // Asignando el contenido de data-proposito del botón que recibió clic
    $('#myModal').find('.modal-body').html($(this).data('proposito'));
});
```